# Passing parameters into callback functions when using .bind

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to pass arguments to a function, but can't figure out how to do this when method chaining .bind.

I suppose my question is two fold:

1) How do you pass the parameters to the callback function (in this case, `printEvent`) when you're using bind?

2) Furthermore, how do you actually pass the `pointerdown` event to the `printEvent` function?

```
var app = {  

  fruit : 'apple',

  printEvent: function(event){
    console.log(event + this.fruit );
  },

  eventListeners:function(){
    var target = document.getElementById('elementId');
    target.addEventListener('pointerdown', this.printEvent(event).bind(this));
  }

}
```

Comment: You mean `target.addEventListener('pointerdown', this.printEvent.bind(this, 'pointerdown'));` ?

Comment: Great, that answers the first question. :) Except, how do I actually pass in the `pointerdown` event itself. Right now, your solution only passes in a string

Comment: I thought you just wanted the string. In that case, just bind `this`. `event` will automatically be passed.

Comment: The relevant docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Comment: As always, you *don't call* the function that you are passing as a callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var app = {
  fruit: 'apple',

  printEvent: function (event) {
    console.log(event.target, event.type, this.fruit)
  },

  eventListeners: function () {
    document.getElementById('elementId').addEventListener('pointerdown', this.printEvent.bind(this))
  }
}
```